# Force a different response format to a form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httpresponse

In a RoR controller, I try to respond to a form.

Based on some processing on the form input in my controller, I want to be able to choose to respond either in CSV or in HTML.
Responding in HTML works fine, but CSV produce a 406 Not Acceptable. Is there a way to force my response so that the user would print or download a csv file ?

Here is my Controller:

```
 #extract
respond_to do |format|
   if condition
          format.csv { render_csv("licenses_#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d")}") } 
   else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @license.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
end
  #extract


  def render_csv(filename = nil)
    filename ||= params[:action]
    filename += '.csv'

    if request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ /msie/i
      headers['Pragma'] = 'public'
      headers["Content-type"] = "text/plain"
      headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=\
0'
      headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"#{filename}\""
      headers['Expires'] = "0"
    else
      headers["Content-Type"] ||= 'text/csv'
      headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"#{filename}\""
    end
    render :layout => false
    end
```

Comment: try by adding this to your form action (`some_action_path(format:csv)`) and then in your controller add `respond_to do |format| format.html  format.csv end`

Comment: Is there no way to take the decision of the response format in the Controller, once the form is submitted ?

Comment: to identify that only we are sending format parameter

Comment: I can specify I want a csv response in the form_for, but then I can not get an html response... Is there a way to specify multiple accepted format ?

Comment: when do you want to get csv or html is there any specific condition?

Comment: Yes, depending on wether a field is empty or not, and if save was successful or not.

Comment: then you can get this in controller like this: 
`respond_to do |format|
    if @some_object.save || params[:field].blank?
        format.html/format.csv
    else
       other format 
    end
end`
use which format you want on which condition and appropriate model object to save and appropriate field value

Comment: That's what I did, but it produce a 406 not acceptable, because the form is expecting an html response. I can force it to CSV but then it wouldn't work anymore for html...

Comment: please add your sample code here

Comment: @anusha I meant done adding the code, sorry :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually just forcing the path of the template did the trick:

```
      format.html { render_csv("licenses_#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d")}", "licenses/create.csv.erb") }
```

Answer (score 1):

change this and try once

```
respond_to do |format|
   if condition
          format.csv { render_csv("licenses_#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d")}") } 
   else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @license.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
end
```

**Update:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#my_form').submit(function(){
          action  = $(this).attr('action').val()
          if($("#filed").val() == '') {
              $("#format").val('csv')
              $(this).attr('action').val(action + $("#format").val())
          }
    })
})
```

change according to your requirement

Comment: You are right, I actually made a mistake when I copy/pasted my code here ... I edited my post. My problem is that the expected response is HTML and not CSV I think...

Comment: @antzi then we will do onething add js to check the parameter value is empty or not based on that we will set format parameter and send to controller and then we will get what we thought  I will update my answer wait